# Remove groups from dataframe where a min value within that group is not below a threshold

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

The dataframe looks like this:

```
id1  id2  value
1    1    35
1    1    23
1    1    20
1    2    5
1    2    50
2    1    42
2    1    3
2    1    12
2    2    64
2    3    34
2    3    1
```

I want to group them by id1 and id2, and remove all rows of a group if the minimum value of that group is not less than 10.
So the result would look like this:

```
id1  id2  value
1    2    5
1    2    50
2    1    3
2    1    12
2    3    34
2    3    1
```

I have tried this:

```
dfmin = df.groupby(["id1", "id2"])["value"].min().reset_index()

df = df[
    dfmin.loc[
        (dfmin["id1"] == df["id1"]) & (dfmin["id1"] == df["id1"]),
        "value",
    ].iat[0]
    < 10
]
```

But I get the error `Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`.

What am I doing wrong and is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `groupby filter`

```
out = df.groupby(['id1', 'id2']).filter(lambda x: x['value'].min() < 10)
```

`out`

```
   id1  id2 value
3   1   2   5
4   1   2   50
5   2   1   42
6   2   1   3
7   2   1   12
9   2   3   34
10  2   3   1
```